# Достать превью (thumbnail) у файла

Tags: python, pyside2, cad

Есть ли возможность достать превьюшку у файла? Работаю с файлами САПР (Компас 3Д) и в проводнике каждый файл имеет миниатюру, должна же быть какая-то возможность достать её ( в операционной системе  же её видно)? В итоге хочу в pyside2 в qtreewidget добавлять эту миниатюру файла

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: нашли ответ? тоже меня интересует этот вопрос

Comment: К сожалению нет, отложил пока на неопределённый срок, хотя кажется, что ответ должен быть простым